# (R) How to combine different types of objects into one row while maintaining its type?

Tags: r

Let's say, I have 3 observations (A, B, C), each with 5 variables(V1, V2, V3, V4, V5) obtained from calculation. If V1, V2 is character, V3 is integer, V4 is double, V5 is logic, how do I combined these 5 variables while maintaining the types?

If I use combine

```
A <- c(V1, V2, V3, V4, V5)
```

then A will become a character vector, with V1, V2, V3, V4, V5 all became a character type. How do I solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can store your data in a list. A list can contain elements of different types.

```
list(V1, V2, V3, V4, V5)
```

An example:

```
A <- list(1L, TRUE, 2.3, "hi")

str(A)
# List of 4
#  $ : int 1
#  $ : logi TRUE
#  $ : num 2.3
#  $ : chr "hi"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. There is nothing like a *mixed atomic vector* type in R. An *atomic* vector is either *logical*, *numeric*, or *character* (with a few more subtle distinctions, see `?vector`). R will automatically convert an atomic vector into a format in which all its elements can be represented without losing information.

The sequence is the following:

- logical: `TRUE`, `FALSE`
- numeric (can also represent logical using the numbers 0 and 1),
  e.g. `c(T, 3)` becomes `c(1,3)`.
- character (can also represent logical and numeric elements), e.g.
  `c(T, "a", 1)` becomes `c("TRUE", "a", "1")`.

So, combining different vector types/modes into one vector with a system that uses *one vector - one type* philosophy this is not possible. But also in this case, no information is lost as described above.

Also have a look here: http://www.r-bloggers.com/type-conversion-and-you-or-and-r/

Also, I do not really understand what you mean by combining. Usually the format to store different data types/variables would be a data frame, not one vector. Here, each variable may be of a different type in each column.

```
data.frame(V1, V2, V3, V4, V5)
```

Comment: Thank you!! Your answer is really helpful. Actually I didn't encounter this problem as first but after I accidentally replaced my latest R-script with a earlier one, it happened. Now I know how to deal with you. Thank you again!!

Comment: You know how to deal with me, or how to deal with the problem? ;) And, if the answer is helpful, feel free to upvote or accept it.

Comment: Please clarify that you mean atomic vectors. A list is also a vector in R.

Comment: @Roland okay, I added that. But could you elaborate on that, I did not know that.

Comment: Read `?vector`and have a look at the R language definition, which calls lists [generic vectors](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#List-objects) and states that "Lists are vectors, and the basic vector types are referred to as atomic vectors where it is necessary to exclude lists."